# Open regedit on a remote workstation

Tags: powershell, remote-access, regedit

Is it possible to write a script that would take a remote workstation ID as input and open `regedit` on that workstation ?

It's sort of the same concept as getting Event logs From EVTX if you know what I mean.

Comment: Are you trying to get a specific registry key from the remote machine, or do you want to invoke something on your machine and have the remote machine's regedit.exe pop up on your screen?

Comment: If you want to get an interactive window anyway, simply start Regedit and connect to the remote registry.

Comment: @Nate Yes I want the regedit.exe window to pop up on my screen but it would be their regedit, so let's say we have to delete keys or something I could do it from my own PC without having to wait for the user to reply to me and then remote on to the machine

Comment: Are you aware that regedit has a built in option to connect to a remote machine?

Comment: No I was not aware, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has always bothered me too, there is no native way to open a remote regedit window.

**But** you could use this quick and dirty method to accomplish it :

```
function Open-RemoteRegistry ($computerName = "127.0.0.1") {
    #add needed assemblies
    Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

    #start regedit
    regedit

    #wait for it to start
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

    #activate regedit window
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Regedit")

    #send Alt F C
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%FC")

    #wait for dialog
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

    #insert computer name and send enter
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$computerName{ENTER}")

    #profit
}

Open-RemoteRegistry (Read-Host "Please provide computer name or IP address")
```

Comment: Thanks @sodawillow , I will give that a shot

Comment: Is that still working for you? For some reason in windows 10 1803 17134.228 it's not working for me anymore, the ALT F C is not registering?